# How to interface Angular 6 with JSON API?

Tags: angular, json-api

I'm using a Rails service with [Netflix fast JSON API](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) to serialize the data. In my Angular App, I have implemented services for all APIs myself, but have a huge number of services to retrieve the data including several resolvers to preload the data before the route is activated.

I was a bit suprised that Angular doesn't simplify interacting with JSON APIs, especially relationships, included resources and models. I found [Angular 2 JSON API](https://github.com/ghidoz/angular2-jsonapi) which simplifies accessing JSON API data and also provides a datastore service. The project is under active development, but does not seem to be used very much.

- Is there a better way to interface with JSON API than using Angular 2 JSON API?
- Are there recommendations to implement resolvers with Angular 2 JSON API?

Comment: what did you end up choosing ?

Comment: I did not pursue this further. I switched to Devise on Rails and use [https://github.com/neroniaky/angular-token](angular-token) for the authorization in Angular.